# Template substitution failing in debug build, but working in optimized build?

Tags: c++, c++11, linker, compiler-optimization, template-specialization

I'm having a weird problem where code that is compiled with `-Ox` compiles fine, but code that is compiled with `-g` fails on link with the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "stupid<dummy>::t", referenced from:
      stupid<dummy>::operator()(int, int) const in main.o
```

The code that reproduces this problem:

```
struct dummy { void operator()(const int a, const int b) const {} ; };

template <typename  T>
struct stupid {
 constexpr static T t = T(); // create a new one;

 stupid() {};
 void operator()(int a, int b) const { t(a, b); }
};


int main()
{
 const stupid<dummy> a;
 a( 1, 2 );
}
```

It appears that when the code is optimized, the function is inlined and no external function call is asked for, but when the code is NOT optimized, the function is called but isn't there?  (I'm not sure why it isn't there...).  This happens in g++ 4.7 and 4.8 and clang 3.2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can get around this by adding

```
template<typename T> constexpr const T stupid<T>::t;
```

after the definition of `stupid`.

This is because calling a non-static member function of 
`t` requires that the address of `t` be taken to use as the `this` pointer.  Taking the address of an object makes it require a runtime instance, which requires the above definition.

Comment: thanks! any idea why it is happening?

Comment: @AndrewSpott: Basically, the program is ill-formed, because `t` is odr-used, but the linker is not required to produce a diagnostic for this error. So it may or may not, but the program is still ill-formed. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547986/what-am-i-allowed-to-do-with-a-static-constexpr-in-class-initialized-data-memb)

Comment: @AndyProwl:  What is "odr-used"?

Comment: @AndrewSpott: I've added some explanation.  See if it is clearer now.

Comment: @VaughnCato:  So, my original guess was kind of correct?  When optimizations are turned on, the function is inlined, and thus no error, but when optimizations aren't on, the address of `t` must be taken, but it doesn't exist...

Comment: @AndrewSpott: I think that is true.