# A curious case with references and static class members

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Take the following piece of code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void print(T &&t){
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

template<class T, T val>
struct Foo{
    static constexpr T value = val;
};

int main(){
    print(Foo<int, 123>::value);
}
```

It refuses to compile under Clang 3.3 and GCC 4.8.1 `("undefined reference to Foo<int, 123>::value")`, which puzzles me because `Foo` does exactly the same as `std::integral_constant`, and the same code runs fine with `integral_constant`. It also fails with plain lvalue reference in the print function. Any explanation regarding this behaviour?

The issue is also present with this quite minimal example:

```
template<class T>
struct Bar{
    static const bool value = true;
};
```

Comment: Your example compiles and runs [on Ideone](http://ideone.com/BJLEuL). Maybe a compiler issue?

Comment: I edited in the compiler versions; Ideone probably uses older stuff.

Comment: Now this is quite interesting: http://www.compileonline.com throws the error but has gcc 4.7.2 just like Ideone.

Comment: Whether using `const` or `constexpr`, it compiles with `-O2` on g++4.8. But not without. Haha

Comment: Clang's consistently not compiling through -O levels.

Comment: Also, if you use `cout` directly (no print(..)) it always compiles on g++.

Comment: This might be a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547986/what-am-i-allowed-to-do-with-a-static-constexpr-in-class-initialized-data-memb). I think by binding it to a reference (universal -> `const&`, not rvalue) you odr-use the variable therefore it has to be defined.

Comment: Why does it compile with integral_constant, though? I just copied in its definition from the libstdc++ sources and it's not working in my source.

Comment: Maybe the libstdc++ provides a definition somewhere else? As a workaround you can use `+Foo<int, 123>::value` (unary plus) to force an rvalue ([thanks litb](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3182557/688659)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the compiler says, there is no reference to the static variable, you must add

```
template<class T, T val>
constexpr T Foo<T, val>::value;
```

after the definition of the class Foo

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be a nice enough solution.