# passing a static constexpr variable by universal reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, static-members, constexpr, one-definition-rule

In the following, `static constexpr` member `L` is initialized in-class `A` and then passed by value or by (universal) reference. The latter fails in Clang but not in GCC, and behaviour is slightly different for member/non-member functions. In more detail:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    static constexpr size_t L = 4;

    template <typename T>
    void member_ref(T&& x) { cout << std::forward<T>(x) << endl; }

    template <typename T>
    void member_val(T x) { cout << x << endl; }
};

template <typename T>
void ref(T&& x) { cout << std::forward<T>(x) << endl; }

template <typename T>
void val(T x) { cout << x << endl; }

int main ()
{
    A().member_ref(A::L);  // Clang: linker error: undefined reference to `A::L'
    A().member_val(A::L);  // fine (prints 4)
    ref(A::L);             // Clang: compiles/links fine, no output
    val(A::L);             // fine (prints 4)
}
```

After some experimentation in isolating the problem from a larger program, I realized that I am accidentally using the address of a `constexpr` variable, although I am only interested in the value.

I want to pass by (universal) reference so that the code is generic and works with large structures without copying. I thought that you could pass anything with a universal reference but it appears this is not the case here. I cannot use a separate (out-of-class) definition for `L` because this is part of a header-only library.

So one workaround can be to generate a value upon call, i.e. say `size_t(A::L)` or something like `A::get_L()` instead of just `A::L`, where (within class `A`)

```
static constexpr size_t get_L() { return L; }
```

but both solutions look a bit clumsy. In my actual code the call is made within the class and looks like `call(0, L, ...)` which appears quite innocent (`0, L` look like values). I'd like to keep the call as simple as possible.

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547370/confusion-about-in-class-initialization-of-static-data-members) and [its follow-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547986/what-am-i-allowed-to-do-with-a-static-constexpr-in-class-initialized-data-memb) pretty much explain what is happening. So could anyone suggest what would be the cleanest way to deal with this?

Comment: Actually, this is independent of the whole rvalue / universal reference business. The point is that you ODR-use `A::L` without providing a definition, and this is a problem using lvalue references as well. In fact, for `constexpr` (but not for `const`) you *always* have to provide out-of-class definition on top of the in-class initializer. Retagging accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for re-tagging. I knew lvalue references had the same problem, I only wanted to give my motivation.

Comment: @TemplateRex: No, not *always*.  Only if the member is odr-used.  See 9.4.2p3.  "... The member shall still be defined
in a namespace scope if it is odr-used (3.2) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not
contain an initializer."

Comment: @BenVoigt it appears you are correct, I must have been confused by experiences with older compilers, tnx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define `A::L` outside its class in a source file

```
constexpr size_t A::L;
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6be422c2dfc56950) using Clang

For header-only code, and if your class `A` is not already a template, you can define a class template `A_<T>` with a `void` default value, and write a typedef for `A` in terms of that

```
template<class = void>
struct A_
{
    static constexpr size_t L = 4;

    template <typename T>
    void member_ref(T&& x) { cout << std::forward<T>(x) << endl; }

    template <typename T>
    void member_val(T x) { cout << x << endl; }

};

template<class T>
constexpr size_t A_<T>::L;

using A = A_<>;
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b4cda733d7ba8d7).

**NOTE**: this business can involve a fair amount of boiler-plate. It is good to note that one can write

```
template
<
    class MyConcept1, 
    class MyConcept2, 
    class YetAnotherConcept
    // more long and well-documented template parameter names
>
struct A
{
    // many static constexpr variabels
};

template<class P1, class P2, class P3 /* many more short parameter names */>
constexpr SomeType A<P1, P2, P3, /* many more */>::some_var;

// many more one-liners.
```

Template parameters just have formal names, they don't have to be the same everywhere (just put them in the *right order* everywhere, though!).

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in my question I cannot do this (header-only library).

Comment: @iavr OK, in that case you can use the class template trick and a typedef to define a special case for the class that you want to use. That will all fit into a header.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this trick. Unfortunately, class `A` may well have 10 more template parameters and I may have 2-3 values like `L` so even repeating the entire template stuff 2-3 times is out of the question (far clumsier than intermediate call-by-value).

Comment: @iavr On the contrary, if `A` already is a class template, then you don't need the extra dummy parameter with a `void` default and the extra typedef. Just provide a `template< /* your list */ > constexpr size_t A< /* your list */>::L;` in the header. Data members of class templates can reside in headers no problem. But yes, you need to do that for every static constexpr variable, no way around that.

Comment: Yes, I understand. The problem is that `/* my list */` may be 2-3 lines of code, so I'd like to only write once.

Comment: @iavr that should be minor annoyance at best, in fact you can use one-letter abbreviations for those parameters for the variable definitions and use more descriptive names for the class template definition itself. If all else fails, just write a macro :-)

Comment: Ok, here is just one example, of which I may have 2-3 different specializations: `template <typename Q, typename... V, typename R, typename T, typename D, typename TR, size_t... N> class join_trav_impl <Q, pack <V...>, R, T, D, TR, sizes <N...> >;`. It is then probably a matter of style. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: @iavr updated the answer to reflect your concern for too much typing. Specializations really come on top of that, ouch, yes I see your pain, but editors and macros should be able to handle that.

Comment: @iavr btw, that example with so many template parameters, cries out for [policy-based design](http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Design-Generic-Programming-Patterns/dp/0201704315) where you factor it into orthogonal components and specialize each of those much smaller building blocks. The main class template `A` just assemblies them by using inheritance and extracts the relevant parts using traits.

Comment: Thanks again for the pointer. I am already trying to do this at least partially, e.g. parameter `TR` above is such a traits class with 10 more definitions. Packs `V...` and `N...` I need them handy (that's why I specialize). `Q,R,T` are the main parameters following a specific pattern for say 10 classes like this one. Plus, by adding 2-3 parameters with defaults you get an one-letter representation to re-use in whatever the class inherits or would define by `using`. E.g. parameter `D` has default `typename D = join_trav <Q, V, R, T>`, ouch :-)

Comment: -1 This is perhaps a workaround, but not a generic solution. What if there is no source file, i.e. if the `static constexpr` variable is defined in some std header?

Comment: @Walter I don't quite understand your remark: for header-only code, you can define the `static constexpr` variable for a template class, and use a typedef to generate a regular class. Boost uses this trick all over the place to keep code header-only. Could you please clarify what exactly you think is worthy of a downvote?