# Taking address of a static member C++ FAQ

Tags: c++

What does [***this***](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/classes-and-objects#in-class-constant) C++ FAQ try to convey ?

> *You can take the address of a static member if (and only if) it has an **out-of-class definition** :*

```
class AE {
    // ...
public:
    static const int c6 = 7;
    static const int c7 = 31;
};

const int AE::c7;   // definition

int f()
{
    const int* p1 = &AE::c6;    // error: c6 not an lvalue
    const int* p2 = &AE::c7;    // ok
    // ...
}
```

However this [*compiles !*](http://ideone.com/PcNzbD)

Comment: What happens if you compile `class AE` and `f()` separately and then link the objects?

Comment: @juanchopanza It compiles with `-O2` and `f()` is essentially a nop. However, it gives a linker error with `-O0`, like the original program does with `-O0`.

Comment: @Csq Yes, I saw and up-voted your answer. Alternatively, `std::cout << p1 << std::endl;` would make in an op.

Comment: Here is a relevant link, originally in my comment to a deleted answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule#Definitions_of_static_const_data_members

Comment: This might probably also be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547370/confusion-about-in-class-initialization-of-static-data-members

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment in the FAQ is very misleading; both `AE::c6` and
`AE::c7` are lvalues.  If there is no definition of `AE::c7`,
the code in question violates the one definition rule:

> An expression is potentially evaluated unless it is an
>   unevaluated operand or a subexpression thereof.  A variable
>   whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is
>   odr-used unless it is an object that satisfies the requirements
>   for appearing in a constant expression and the lvalue-to-rvalue
>   conversion is immediately applied. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every
>   non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that
>   program; no diagnostic required.

In practice, the linker will generally generate an error *if*
the compiler actually needed the address of the object.  In your
case, if `p2` isn't used later, then the compiler won't need the
address, since optimization will remove the definition of `p1`.
An even more frequent case where this occurs are things like the
following:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back( AE::c6 );
```

Since `std::vector<>::push_back` takes a reference, there is no
immediate lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, and a definition is
required.  In practice, `std::vector<>::push_back` is a template
function (usually inline), so the compiler can see into its
implementation, and propagate the value down into the function
to the place where the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion actually
occurs, and the code will compile and work.  But it is still
formally undefined behavior.

Answer (score 9):

You use `-O2` to compile. The compiler can optimize away the `const int* p1 = &AE::c6;` assignment (as it has no effect) and therefore it does not need the address of `AE::c6` in the final code, that's why it compiles.

It gives a linker error without optimization.

You also get a linker error if you start to use `p1` (e.g. `std::cout << p1 << p2 << std::endl;`) [Link](http://ideone.com/pyguLP)

Comment: Okay, I'll say the same thing here too (as I said was in one of deleted answer), the comment `// error: c6 not an lvalue` in FAQ IMO is misleading, which appears to be a syntactical error on first glance. Linker error was obvious, but surprisingly unknown to me after optimization